# Node.js halts when console window is scrolled

Tags: node.js, windows, performance, event-loop

If you run the following script in Node.js under Windows (at least 8)

```
const init = +new Date;
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(+new Date - init);
}, 1000);
```

and drag the thumb of a scroll bar of console window, the output of the script looks similar to

```
1001
2003  // long drag here
12368 // its result
13370
14372
```

Looks like Node.js' event loop halts during the scroll. The same thing should happen to asynchronous actions inside of `http` package. Thus leaving a visible terminal window is dangerous to the running server.

How do I change the code to avoid such behavior?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. It's quite simple, and @Aminadav is correct: whilst the console window is scrolling it stops displaying the output. This doesn't stop the Node.js process in the background, and neither does it stop the Node.js process from producing output (you can prove this by outputting to screen and file at the same time). What you also haven't told us is whether you're running this in CMD or Powershell.

Comment: It's running in `cmd`. It does halt if you use `console.log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two pieces of information in the node documentation that may give some clues for the reason of that behaviour:

an excerpt from [Console](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console):

> **Warning:** The global console object's methods are neither consistently synchronous like the browser APIs they resemble, nor are they consistently asynchronous like all other Node.js streams. See the note on process I/O for more information.

an excerpt from [A note on process I/O](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o):

> **Warning:** Synchronous writes block the event loop until the write has completed. This can be near instantaneous in the case of output to a file, but under high system load, pipes that are not being read at the receiving end, or with slow terminals or file systems, its possible for the event loop to be blocked often enough and long enough to have severe negative performance impacts.

And it seems that partial solution can be built using method you already proposed:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const init = +new Date;
setInterval(() => {
    fs.write(1,String(+new Date - init)+'\n',null,'utf8',()=>{});
}, 1000);
```

It still blocks UI if you start selection, but doesn't stop processing:

```
2296
3300  // long pause here when selection was started
4313  // all those lines printed at the same time after selection was aborted
5315
6316
7326
8331
9336
10346
11356
12366
13372
```

Comment: I didn't even know there is documentation on `Console`! Great, that's what I expected to hear.

Answer (score 6):

NodeJS is not halted while scrolling or selecting text. The only functions that send data to stdout are halted.
In your server, you are able to send log data to a file, and this way your server will not halt.

For example, see this code:

```
const init = +new Date;
var str=''
setInterval(() => {
    x=(+new Date - init).toString();;
    str+=x + '\n'
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(str)
},5000)
```

I have selected text during the first 5 seconds, and this was the result:

```
C:\me>node a
1002
2002
3002
4003
```

You can see that there is no 'pause'.

As you see, the first event loop `setInterval` wasn't halted, because there is no `console.log` inside.

Now, when you use an output file for logging, you can view live log using [`tail -f`](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/). This will show you each new line in the output file.

Comment: I know it's `console.log` that halts execution, but 1) why? 2) how to write into console without this effect? I don't have `tail` on Windows.

Comment: is not hating executing, the output is delayed

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez: On windows; it is halting.

Answer (score 5):

Your console is actually pausing when you scroll or click in the console, as it's entering into select mode. Have a look in the title bar as it's paused it will likely say select.

To prevent this behavior, edit the properties of the command prompt, and unselect "quick edit mode".

Comment: Console UI settings shouldn't affect the way server works. I've just edited the question to explicitly ask for code.

Comment: Run the same code in a 3rd party console such as ConEmu or cmder and you will find that it works fine. This is specifically a problem with the windows command prompt pausing execution of your application while scrolling

Comment: Execution of which thread of my application? Why Node.js doesn't run event loop in a background thread on Windows then? Either this is a Node.js bug, or they've thought it should be solveable with code. I suspect it's the second (i.e. `console.log` might be waiting synchronously until it can print, and you should use something like `fs.write(1, ...)`).

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to make your console.log and console.error always asynchronous on all platforms, you can do this by using `fs.write` to fd 1 (stdout) or fd 2 (stderr).

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')

// used by console.log
process.stdout.write = function write (str) {
  fs.write(1, str, ()=>{})
}

// used by console.error
process.stderr.write = function write (str) {
  fs.write(2, str, ()=>{})
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Scrolling the console with this fix in place caused the first 2 console.log statements to complete without blocking, but on the 3rd one, the console.log blocked once again.