# Holding scroll bar of prompt window appears to freeze program executions

Tags: python, windows, cmd, scrollbar, prompt

I was working on a program and by chance happened to notice a strange behavior with my anaconda prompt. A running program is paused simply by left-double-click-holding the scroll bar of the prompt window. Leave the hold and it takes off from where it froze.

Came across: [Node.js halts when console window is scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068773/node-js-halts-when-console-window-is-scrolled/48183045)

The highest voted (at the time of this writing) suggests that the processing is NOT halted while the UI/stdout is.

> "NodeJS is not halted while scrolling or selecting text. The only functions that send data to stdout are halted."

But, i found it otherwise. The processing itself appears to halt. In-fact a few comments there too do mention that it does halt execution. Following these examples you "should" be able to replicate the behavior.

Example 1: Anaconda, Python, Win7

```
import time

def countdown_timer(wait_seconds):
    wait_seconds = int(wait_seconds)
    while wait_seconds>=0:
        mins, secs = divmod(wait_seconds, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        wait_seconds -= 1

countdown_timer(5)
with open("THE AWAITED ONE IS FINALLY HERE.txt", "w"): pass
```

The above python script should make a text file in 5 seconds. Run it and hold the scroll bar (within 5 sec) --> Counter stops and the file is NOT created even after 10 seconds past.
Leave the hold and it starts the counter from exactly where it stopped and creates the file AFTER the counter returns to 00:00.
Which means, not only the UI/stdout halted, but rather the processing itself froze!

Example 2: CMD, batch script, Win7

```
REM file name: create_file_eventually.bat 
@echo off
for /L %%n in (1,1,50000) do echo %%n
echo "sorry to keep you waiting my friend, did you miss me?">"THE AWAITED ONE IS FINALLY HERE.txt"
```

This does something similar. It prints out a number series till 50000. That should give you sufficient time (~ 5sec) to catch-hold the scroll-bar before the count reaches 50000.
Try halting it within time and it will NOT create the file UNTIL you release the hold. Also note the count restarting exactly from where it stopped.

Other OS? - Not tested.  |  Win10 and higher? - Not tested.  |  Replicated with all/any running script? - Not tested on larger scale.  |  Want me to capture the behavior in a video? - let me know

It perhaps is not a big issue with small-time programmers like me but it still is a very little bothering because i run python programs for money trading. Imagine, the slightest delay or interrupt in the operation may mean a big blunders/loss.

My humble obvious questions:

1. Is this a known thing?
2. Is this a bug or an intentional behavior?
3. If Intentional: Who - windows i suppose?
4. Any known work around?
5. How about (white/black) hat hackers?
   Now, imagine the interruptions for following programs!

```
daily_push_date_of_nuking_some_country_by_24_hrs_if_signatures_found()
# or
pay_interest_in_time()
```

Theoretically, a bot (even an external mechanical bot) or a child can simply halt a running program simply by holding the scroll --> leaving **not much trace** of actually hacking the computer to do so.

6. money, nukes, hackers .. is it an unnecessary panic?

-tnx

Comment: What sort of attack do you have in mind that consists of **not** executing code?

Comment: @IInspectable There are innumerable. In general, anything that is time dependent and a delay will compromise it. Here's something wrt trading - 1. Enter a trade but delay in applying the stoploss may result in margin call. 2. Enter a trade with a delayed counter hedge trade. 3. A delayed entry to a signal.. etc

Comment: I wasn't thinking of exploiting a broken implementation. I was talking about an actual attack, crossing a security boundary, leaking secrets, that sort of thing.

Comment: @IInspectable I m pretty sure there will be many Sir, except, if told they all can be categorized as broken implementation as there is always a bug fix.